# Python: remove item from list if item has a number

Tags: python

If I have a list  that looks like this:

`lst = ['unfavorable movements in foreign exchange rates','0 derivative liabilities (b): foreign exchange contracts $ 516 $ 41 $', 'institutions to protect against foreign exchange risks', 'value derivative assets (a): foreign exchange contracts $ 138 $ 12 $']`
I want to remove any items from this if a there is a number that shows up. In other words, I want my final list to look like:

`lst = ['unfavorable movements in foreign exchange rates', 'institutions to protect against foreign exchange risks']`

I "kill" the other items because the items contained a number. How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this by writing some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
>>> [ item for item in lst if not any(char.isdigit() for char in item) ]
['unfavorable movements in foreign exchange rates', 'institutions to protect against foreign exchange risks']
>>>
```

Comment: 7 seconds quicker than me :-)

Comment: I didn't know about the `char.isdigit()`. Thanks

Comment: @AdemÖztaş When I looked at your answer, the syntax makes absolute sense but I keep getting an empty list when I try `[ item for item in lst if not any(char.isdigit() for char in item) ]` ... any idea why?

Comment: @AdemÖztaş I was able to solve my issue with the `__builtin__`: `[item for item in lst if not __builtin__.any(item.isdigit() for char in item)]`